# Relation between affine restriction and projective closures.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

(I have **bolded** my principal question $\downarrow$).

Reading through [Algebraic Curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ewfulton/CurveBook.pdf) by W. Fulton I've stumbled upon a couple of problems on proposition three from section 4.3 (pg. 48).

A short recap of the definitions:

> For algebraic $V\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ define $I^*=\langle\{f^*\in k[X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1}]\mid f\in I(V)\}\rangle$.
>
> For algebraic $V\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ define $I_*=\{F_*\in \mid F\in I(V)\}$.
>
> $H_\infty = \{[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]\in \mathbb{P}^n\mid x_{n+1}=0\}$

Where $I(V)$ represents the polyonimials that vanish on $V$, and $V(I)$ the zeroes of the ideal $I$; and $f^*$ and $F_*$ represent homogenization and dehomogenization respectively.

Now, point 7 states that

> If no irreducible component of $V\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ contains or is contained in $H_\infty$, then $V_*\subsetneq \mathbb{A}^n$ and $(V_*)^*=V$.

In this argument, I don't understand why it's only necessary to prove the result for irreducible $V$ (the proof with this assumption I undersntad). Even if the result is true for the irreducible componentes of a set $V=\cup_i V_i$, it could happen that every $V_i$ is proper but their union is $\mathbb{A}^n$. **I don't see how to fill this gap.**

Edit: @math54321's comment has solved the $V\subsetneq\mathbb{A}^n$ part for me, I'm still stuck on $(V_*)^*=V$.

It would be nice to see an example where $V$ contains $H_\infty$ but none of it's irreducible componets

On point 6, which states

> If $V\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ is non empty, then no component of $V^*$ lies in or contains $H_\infty$

I can't find the point in the proof where the hypothesis of irreducibility is used. To me it seems to be proving that the projective closure of any proper algebraic set neither contains nor is contained in $H_\infty$.

I haven't been able to proof the supposedly very simple $(V^*)_*=V$ from point 1.

Finally, if this were true it would solve a couple of my problems:

$$V=\bigcup^N V_i \implies V_* = \bigcup^N {V_i}_*$$

but I can't prove left $\subseteq$ right.

I'll be really grateful for any help, even very partial. Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbb{A}^n$ is irreducible, so it can't be a union of finitely many closed $V_i$. I think you're right in point 6 that $V$ doesn't need to be irreducible. For $(V^*)_* = V$, you can probably just check that they have the same ideal of vanishing polynomials.

Comment: For $W\subset \Bbb{P}^n$ irreducible when do we have that $W\cap \Bbb{A}^n$ is not dense in $W$ ? When $W\cap (\Bbb{P}^n-\Bbb{A}^n)$ is dense in $W$, ie. when $W$ is contained in $\Bbb{P}^n-\Bbb{A}^n=H_\infty\cong \Bbb{P}^{n-1}$. Thus for $V\subset \Bbb{P}^n$ non-irreducible, that $V\cap \Bbb{A}^n$ is dense in $V$ is the same as each of its  (closure's) irreducible component is not contained in $H_\infty$.

Comment: @math54321 Thanks! That part makes sense now. How do I show $(V_*)^*=V$ though? Assuming the result for irreducible sets. (Noticing the order of the $*$ I mean as in 7, I think I was able to show $(V^*)_*=V$ already.